# Getting Smash to remember the character I picked between games

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

One of the biggest annoyances so far in SSBU is the fact that in between rounds of Smash, your character choice is seemingly reset, and you are forced to re-select your character.   This is annoying when I want to practice vs CPU players, because it becomes increasingly infuriating to have to re-select the character and his costume every single game.

Obviously, I'm pretty sure that previous titles, especially Brawl, remembered your fighter choice in between rounds. Now I've looked throughout the options and I can't seem to find an option to stop the game from forgetting which character I'm playing. I know this is an issue specifically on what I play, because the game will remember my pick for the CPU character, but not for the player.

Comment: This--in combination to having players' names left active between rounds--also means that you have to get your hands on a player's controller to take them out in between games if they've decided to walk away. This is only worse if they have a wireless controller they've taken with them! I don't believe there's a specific way to disable either of these, but I'll be interested to see if someone's found one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any way to, according to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/SmashBrosUltimate/comments/a47c53/is_it_driving_anyone_crazy_that_you_need_to/) [threads](https://www.reddit.com/r/smashbros/comments/a4j45v/has_anyone_figured_out_how_to_make_the_game_keep/) I've found online. The only way I've seen mentioned is to set the "First to Win" rule to 5, but that's likely not going to work for all matches.

Answer (score 1):

It now remembers!

I was playing some lvl. 6 CPU rounds the other day and it remembers your option! Even my friend started playing and it remembers.

Comment: Has there been an update to the game which changed this behavior?

Comment: This is a Big Deal if true. Just saying "it works now!" isn't especially convincing (especially for those of us without access to the game to test). If you could add some links to others who have found the same, or even a timestamped link to a streamed tournament where this happens, it would greatly improve the credibility of your answer (and get an upvote from me!)

Comment: I'm downvoting this as, from [this timestamped link](https://youtu.be/haWMqPr7I1U?t=578) of a tournament last weekend, it appears characters are still not remembered. If you have any evidence to the contrary, please post it!